# Suppressing Valgrind errors from GTK+

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, valgrind

I have an application that uses GTK+ and Glade; running Valgrind with the memcheck tool outputs about 2,000 errors. Does anyone have a good suppression file they can share for GTK applications?

I tried these, but each still leaves me with ~900 errors:

- http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/development/nip2.supp
- http://www.gnome.org/~johan/gtk.suppression
- https://gist.github.com/758760

A copy of the code I'm working with can be found [here](http://students.cs.byu.edu/~cs240ta/fall2011/download/projects/chess/chess.tgz). Do `make run` to build the GUI (there is nothing but the GUI in this copy of the code).

Comment: Look here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Valgrind and (on ubuntu) use suppression file `/usr/share/glib-2.0/valgrind/glib.supp`

Answer (score 2):

Try this, worked for me:
http://lug.rose-hulman.edu/code/projects/grits/repository/revisions/master/raw/src/gtk.suppression

I've uploaded my modified version here: [paste.org/47748](http://paste.org/47748)

Here's my valgrind command line, but I think setting G_SLICE and G_DEBUG doesn't help as much as editing the suppressions file:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --num-callers=15 --suppressions=gtk.supp --log-file=vgdump ./runner
```

Answer (score 1):

You may already have seen it as you use the GTK suppression file from Johan Dahlin, but there's a page about [Valgrind and GTK](https://wiki.gnome.org/Valgrind) on the GNOME wiki.